# Making theme translation available crashes sidebar

Tags: sidebar, multi-language

I have added this snipped to enable possibility to translate a website:

```php
    function florial_setup()
{
    /*
        * Make theme available for translation.
        * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
        * If you're building a theme based on florial, use a find and replace
        * to change 'florial' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
        */
    load_theme_textdomain('florial', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'florial_setup');
```

I have made necessary settings in pot and po files to translate website to local language and it actually works. But after adding this snippet, the sidebar disappeared in shop page and in single product page appeared Blog sidebar. After I remove this snipped everything gets okay - I see right sidebar in shop page and no sidebar in single product page.

How this code snippet can cause such issues, do you have any ideas?
In theme support I got answer, that these are my custom issues and it is beyond their scope of support. But anyway is it possible that theme code causes such issue?

Comment: Where did you add that code? What theme are you using? Are you sure there isn't already a function named `florial_setup`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, right, `florial_setup` function exists in parent theme. Renamed it and the problem is gone. Thank you!
BTW, theme name is Florial and the snipped was added in `functions.php`.